# How does HTTP probing work in Azure IaaS Load Balanced Set with Multiple Sites on VMs

Tags: azure, iis, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

I have a classic Azure IaaS VM deployment with a load balanced set of endpoints. The loadbalancer has endpoints for 80 and 443. The VMs have multiple sites on them and hostheaders are used to route traffic to the right site. Let's say there are two sites in IIS with host headers:
app.contoso.com
api.contoso.com

And the vnet/cloud service is contoso.cloudapp.net

Will the http probing on the load balanced request contoso.cloudapp.net with whatever 'probe path" I specified appended? For example, http://contoso.cloudapp.net/statuscheck. So that what I need to do is have a third IIS site that is the default site or has contoso.cloudapp.net as the hostheader and return 200 when statuscheck is requested if I want the VM to be in the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Health probes are defined per endpoint. The Http probe can point to a URL in the VM and it will work as long as the VM responds to the probe with appropriate return code. You cannot have multiple probes for a endpoint though.

Comment: But does the URL get built with the cloudapp url like I noted above?

Comment: I'm completely lost here.  So I can point the probe to https://google.com and it will be marked as healthy unless Google has an outage?